# Removing words containing expression?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking to remove any words containing "oil". I thought `\b` grabs any word containing "oil" but seems to only replace the word itself:

```
String str = "foil boil oil toil hello";
str = str.replaceAll("\\boil\\b", "");
```

Output:

> foil boil toil hello

Desired output:

> hello

Comment: `\boil\b` grabs the word "oil" itself, when it's nested within word boundaries. Please see [Reference: What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word boundary asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not.

You can use the following regex:

```
String s = "foil boil oil toil hello";
s = s.replaceAll("\\w*oil\\w*", "").trim();
System.out.println(s); //=> "hello"
```

Or if you want to be strict on just matching letters.

```
String s = "foil boil oil toil hello";
s = s.replaceAll("(?i)[a-z]*oil[a-z]*", "").trim();
System.out.println(s); //=> "hello"
```

Comment: @co_starr: "Java"? Mention that in your post or tags (preferably both). "An" error? Mention which one, it may help.

Comment: okay to add on to the regex, if I have something that like: http://t.co/6lyIr3mY2u http://t.co/   how can I remove that whole sequence? (it contains http: at the front it just hyperlinked when I posted it)

Comment: @co_starr Put that in another question. Don't ask new questions in comments or answers.

Comment: @Unihedron will do ... in 90 minutes

Answer (score 3):

Simply match with prefixing and suffixing `[a-z]*`!

Match (and replace):

```
/ ?[a-z]*oil[a-z]* ?/
```

[View an online regex demo.](http://regex101.com/r/mK6qI4/2)

Comment: For matching this suffices, but for replacing you need to get rid of the spaces. hwnd's `.trim()` is a bit sneaky - it works, but only because there is only one word remaining.

Comment: Ah -- that's better. But (I didn't try it) will it not remove the spaces on *either* side now? Will `xx boil yy` become `xxyy`?

Comment: @Jongware For replacing you would have to match my regex and replace with `" "`. For every iteration of `replaceAll()` this would keep a space left in place.

Comment: Got it -- followed by a `.trim()`, so the output will not start or end with a space. That may be easier than expanding the regex beyond readability.